# Median of a finite set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the set
$$S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,\ldots,123456789\},$$
which consists of all positive integers whose digits strictly increase from left to right. This set is finite. What is the median of the set?

I thought the answer was just $\frac{123456789 + 1}{2}$ because if the set is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\},$ the median is $\frac{1+5}{2} = 3.$ So I'm not sure why my answer is incorrect.

Comment: You can see that your style of reasoning wouldn't give the correct answer for $\{1, \ldots, 9, 12, 13\}$ either.

Comment: *whose digits striclty increase from left to right*  @Etotheipi do not confuse this with the set containing *all* integers from $1$ to $123456789$.

Comment: How do I find the median when the set does not contain all the integers from 1 to 123456789?

Answer (score 2):

As a hint to the correct solution, you should recognize that there are in fact $\binom{9}{1}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{3}+\dots+\binom{9}{9}=2^9-1=511$ elements in your set.

Try thinking about where the halfway point might be taking this observation into account.

Comment: is it the 256th term?

Comment: Yes, of course... as per the definition of median.  Now, the trick is to figure out what the $256$'th term *looks like*.  Try answering questions like "how many digits" it has and "which digits" it has.  Also, you need to understand *why* what I said above in my hint is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that this set doesn't contain all the positive integers. Note that $11$, $22$, $21$ etc. are missing. You found a pattern for the set of the first $n$ positive integers. Not the set of the first $n$ positive integers whose digits increase from left to right.